# Problems when applying selenium on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I wrote a web spider on Win7 before and it worked very good before. However, I got the following error reports after updating my system to Win10. Could you give me some suggestions to solve this problem?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:/Python27/study/study.py", line 4, in <module>
     driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
 line 59, in __init__
     self.binary, timeout),   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py",
 line 47, in __init__
     self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
 line 66, in launch_browser
     self._wait_until_connectable()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
 line 105, in _wait_until_connectable
     raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile " WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s
 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it
 for details.
```

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Are you sure your problems are Win10-related? Usually it doesn't matter much which platform you use Firefox on. The behavior towards Selenium is pretty much the same, no matter if you run Firefox on any Windows version, on Mac or even on Android.

Comment: To kimmy: thank you for your comments. I think you are right, Buaban pointed out that it is the firefox version issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is Firefox version issue.

1. Uninstall Firefox
2. Download older version such as https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/41.0/win32/en-US/
3. Install it
4. Run test again

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I will try it.